# powershell: Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near '/'." '

Tags: powershell

Can someone please help me with this error:

> Error,0,The job failed.
>   03/19/2015 12:51:59,A job step received an error at line 75 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is '    $SqlAdapter2.Fill($DataSet2)'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near '/'."  '.  Process Exit Code -1.  The step failed.,00:00:02,0,0,,,,0

My code is:

```
#Exceute the procedure and place the .csv file on server

    $CurrentDate = Get-Date
    $CurrentDate = $CurrentDate.ToShortDateString()
    $PreviousDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString()

       $server2 = "XXXXXXX"
        $database2 = "XXXXXX"
        $query2 = "exec XXX.XXXXX_XXXXX_daily_report"+$PreviousDate+","+$PreviousDate 



     $extractFile2 = "C:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX_daily_Report"+($CurrentDate)+".csv"

        $connectionTemplate2 = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
        $connectionString2 = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate2, $server2, $database2)
        $connection2 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $connection2.ConnectionString = $connectionString2

        $command2 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $command2.CommandText = $query2
        $command2.Connection = $connection2
        $command2.CommandTimeout=0 

        $SqlAdapter2 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        $SqlAdapter2.SelectCommand = $command2
        $DataSet2 = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        $SqlAdapter2.Fill($DataSet2)
        $connection2.Close()

        # dump the data to a csv
        $DataSet2.Tables[0] | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $extractFile2
```

Comment: Are we missing some other code?  It looks like you're creating a `$DataSet2` object and then trying to use it as the overload for the `$SqlAdapter2.Fill()` method.  You normally need to have some data as your input for a method like that.

I find it difficult to help you, as I don't understand what you want to do here.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the issue is the format of the date. I am not a SQL expert, but I would suggest something like `$PreviousDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` and see if that fixes your problem. I don't think SQL likes slashes in the date format.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't opened the connection yet.  That is the issue.

Right after this line:

```
$connection2.ConnectionString = $connectionString2
```

Add this line:

```
$connection2.Open()
```

Answer (score -1):

In the exec statement, you might need to put a space between these two pieces:
_daily_report"+$PreviousDate

Also, you can just do this -- write the whole SQL command as one string:

$query2 = "exec XXX.XXXXX_XXXXX_daily_report $PreviousDate, $PreviousDate"

because Powershell will insert the values of those variables into the string for you.